# $\lim_{n \to +\infty} E[ \vert X_n \vert] = 0 \implies \lim_{n \to +\infty} E[ (X_n)^2] = 0$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence real random variables which are uniformly bounded $P$-a.s. If
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} E[ \vert X_n \vert] = 0
$$
does this imply
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} E[ (X_n)^2] = 0
$$
as well?

It would if the variables were bounded by 1. But what if that's not case? I've looked at Jensen's Inequality but it seems to be the wrong way around

Comment: Why is $1$ special?  You say that they are uniformly bounded so $|X_{n}| \leq C$.  Hence $Y_{n} = C^{-1} X_{n}$ is bounded by $1$ and $E(|Y_{n}|) \to 0$.  At the same time, $E(Y_{n}^{2}) \to 0$ if and only if $E(X_{n}^{2}) \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that $|X_n| \leq M \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then
$$E[X^2]=E[|X|^2]=\int|X_n|^2d\mathbb{P}\leq \int|X_n| Md\mathbb{P}=M\int|X_n|d\mathbb{P}$$
Since $\lim _{n \to \infty}E[|X_n|]<\infty $, this implies
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int|X_n|^2d\mathbb{P}\leq M\lim_{n \to \infty} \int|X_n|d\mathbb{P} < \infty $$

Comment: Why the downvote?